# Allow traffic to rabbitMQ service from Istio

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, envoyproxy

I've setup a K8S-cluster in GKE and installed RabbitMQ (from the marketplace) and Istio (via Helm). I can access rabbitMQ from pods until I enable the envoy proxy to be injected into these pods, but after that the traffic will not reach rabbitMQ, and I can't figure out how to enable traffic to the rabbitmq service.

There is a service *rabbitmq-rabbitmq-svc* (in the *rabbitmq* namespace) that is of type LoadBalancer.
I've tried a simple busybox when I don't have envoy running and then I have no trouble telneting to rabbitmq (port 5672), but as soon as I try with automatic envoy injection envoy prevents the traffic.
I tried unsuccessfully to add a DestinationRule. (I've added a rule but it makes no difference)

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-rabbitmq-svc
spec:
  host: rabbitmq.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: LEAST_CONN
```

It seems like it should be a simple solution, but I can't figure it out... :/

**UPDATE**
Turns out it was a simple error in the hostname, ended up using this and it works:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-rabbitmq-svc
spec:
  host: rabbitmq-rabbitmq-svc.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: Have you enabled istio on rabbitmq ? What does the "istio-proxy" container of rabbitmq deployment says ?

Comment: No, RabbitMQ is running outside of Istio.
It turned out to be a simple error in the hostname. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple error in the hostname, the correct one was `rabbitmq-rabbitmq-svc.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local`

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I needed to do to get RabbitMQ clusters to work within Istio is to annotate the RabbitMQ pods as such:

```
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
spec:
  override:
  statefulSet:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            #annotate rabbitMQ pods to only redirect traffic on ports 15672 and 5672 to Envoy proxy sidecars.
            traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts: "15672, 5672"          
            traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeOutboundPorts: "15672, 5672"
```

For some reason the exclude port annotations weren't working so I just flipped it by using include port annotations. In my case, the global Istio config is controlled by another team in the company so perhaps there's a clash when trying to use the exclude port annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe encounter the same problem with you before. But my app can connect rabbitmq by envoy after declaring epmd with 4369 port in rabbitmq service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    targetPort: 5672
    name: message
  - port: 4369
    targetPort: 4369
    name: epmd
  - port: 15672
    targetPort: 15672
    name: management
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
```