# Rabbitmq service not reachable within k3s pods?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, istio, rancher, k3s

I have the following setup: k3s installation and istio as ingress controller,

problem we face that rabbitmq service is not reachable from within pods internally.

- A Service that has rabbitmq port exposed [5671] -> `type: ClusterIP`

  ```
   $ kubectl describe service rabbit-svc -n rabbit
   ......
   Type:              ClusterIP
   IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
   IP Families:       IPv4
   IP:                10.43.139.126
   IPs:               10.43.139.126
   ......
   Port:              https  443/TCP
   TargetPort:        443/TCP
   Endpoints:         10.42.0.222:443
   Port:              rabbitmq  5671/TCP
   TargetPort:        5671/TCP
   Endpoints:         10.42.0.222:5671
  ```
- if I try to connect to that service via clusterIP from inside the machine outside k3s pods, it responds back

  ```
  openssl s_client -connect 10.43.139.126:5671
  CONNECTED(00000003)
  ```
- if I try to connect to the pod from istio pod via the service k8s fqdn, it gives connection refused

  ```
  openssl s_client -connect rabbit-svc.rabbit.svc.cluster.local:5671
  139693269235008:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
  139693269235008:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
  connect:errno=111
  ```

Any idea why this is happening though I have another port from inside that rabbitmq service exposed via 443 and it respond back fine [ that's just to rule out DNS issues ]

Answer (score 0):

The connection error:111 is might be due to below concerns and can you check on this :

- Check whether the Port 5671 is open or blocked by using  nmap or
  telnet.
- Check if there are any firewalls blocking this port/host. Try to
  disable the firewall and have a check
- Seems to be your istio is having SSL certificate enabled - this
  blocking the port 5671 to reach the connection.   Can you disable the
  SSL certificate and have a check. If it is connected then SSL
  certificate is the reason which is blocking this. In this case you
  need to make sure 5671 Port should accept the SSL certificate. If
  there is no SSL certificate enabled then the first two points might
  be the reason.
- Can you try by using this command  `echo | openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> | head`

Refer to this [RabbitMQ troubleshooting doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html) for more information

Comment: well based on my tests the port is listening and like I mentioned in the question , it can be reached outside the pods, and if you don't pass in the certificate at least the connection would be opened , I also tried from different pods , not just the istio pod

Comment: As you are using FQDN ,can try you adding [istio Virtualservice](https://codeburst.io/istio-by-example-5189edd043da) and [Destination Rule](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#LoadBalancerSettings) to route the traffic to  the defined service.

Comment: well , I added the virtual service along with the gateway , and since that didn't work , I decided to check why, and came to this problem that ingress gateway pod can't establish the connection to the rabbitmq

Comment: @AhMaDAbUIeSa : Even i'm checking on this but mean while can you check whether you have given the correct format of FQDN hostname as `<name of the service>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`. You can check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56106626/19230181).

Comment: but I can see your service name as `rabbit-svc` and name space as `rabbit`. So, try the following : `openssl s_client -connect rabbit-svc.rabbit.svc.cluster.local:5671`
let me know if you find any errors.

Comment: yes you are right , that was just a typo , from different trials , and yes I am using the correct name [ as I said in the question , I can connect to port 443 , which is another port that exposes an https process ]

Comment: Can you check this [link1](https://community.freepbx.org/t/unable-to-load-ssl-certificate-for-port-5161-but-port-443-works/72570/2) and [Link2](https://forum.howtoforge.com/threads/apache2-openssl-s_client-error.85910/)

Comment: @AhMaDAbUIeSa : Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful and the issue resolved?. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.